# Copy data from a Subset of Worksheets in a workbook and pasting to a master worksheet, disregarding the standard mastersheets

Tags: excel, vba, variables

Hello to the community and thank you in advance for your assistance. I have created a workbook that has a variable number of worksheets most of which have variable name. There are however, 4 worksheets that will not change and I do not want data copied from them. The code I am attempting is below: If I am way off base, please let me know.

V/R
Doug

```
Private Sub GroupReport_Click()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long
Dim CopyRng As Range
Dim Disreguard(1 To 4) As String

Disreguard(1) = "RDBMergeSheet"
Disreguard(2) = "0 Lists"
Disreguard(3) = "0 MasterCrewSheet"
Disreguard(4) = "00 Overview"

   ' Delete the summary sheet if it exists.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

' Add a new summary worksheet.
Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"


' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
' summary worksheet.
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> Disreguard.Worksheets.Name Then
        Last = LastRow(DestSh)
        Set CopyRng = sh.Rows("21")
        CopyRng.Copy
        With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With

    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this line will not work for you:

```
If sh.Name <> Disreguard.Worksheets.Name Then
```

The Disreguard variable is an array, but not an object in VBA, so there are no methods you can access with the dot operator. You would have to loop through the array's contents and check each item against the string you're testing.

You can add a function to test it like this:

```
Private Function toDisreguard(ByRef list() as String, ByRef searchString As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(list) To UBound(list)
        If (searchString = list(i)) Then
            toDisreguard = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

    toDisreguard = False
End Function
```

And then pass the array along with the sheet name to test like so:

```
If (toDisreguard(Disreguard, sh.Name) = False) Then
```

Also, the LastRow() function is not defined from what you posted. Is this a function you created?

In fact, you could just keep track of the last row yourself since you're rebuilding the "RDBMergeSheet" worksheet each time you run this. You can start by setting Last = 1 and then increment along the way. And one last thing, you should probably test to see if there is any data in row 21 for each sheet so you're not copying a blank row:

```
' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
' summary worksheet.
Last = 1

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If (toDisreguard(Disreguard, sh.Name) = False) Then
        'Last = LastRow(DestSh)
        If (Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Rows("21")) > 0) Then
            Set CopyRng = sh.Rows("21")
            CopyRng.Copy
            With DestSh.Cells(Last, "A") ' notice i changed this as well
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With
            Last = Last + 1
        End If
    End If
Next
```